# Split the text between the start and end words from a long String using Regex Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Extracted a threaded email body using pywin32 and I need to extract the signature part alone from the body.
I tried to split the text using the signature start as starting word and the next email From as the Ending word.
For ex: 'With Regards' will be the starting word and 'Von' will be the ending word.

Body of the email:

```
Dear Sir,
Your Order is ready and tested. It will be shipped shortly.
Let me know once you receive it.

With Regards,
dcabv,
vce technologies
vce.com
cont:+00440044


From: abc@gsn.com
To:csd@scb.com
Sub: product

Dear Sir,
Can I get the update of my order?

With Regards,
abc
cont:+46346466

Von: csd@scb.com
Gesendet:abc@gsn.com
Sub: Order Placed

Dear Sir,
your order has placed. 
you will receive it shortly.

With Regards,
dcabv,
vce technologies
vce.com
cont:+00440044
```

Another Text:

```
a = """
Best regards,

 

i.V. Cap. Mars Wel

Chief Superintendent

========================== 

P E N T   H O L E

Sahrts-HC

Elba 379

D- 259 Ham

Tel:    +58 58 58585-584    

Mobile: +91 758 858 5875 

Fax:    +47 47 85885-855

Sitz: Ham, HA 5772


 

 

 

Von: Korayae Vinay <Korayae.Vinay@robo.com> 
Gesendet: Donnes, 19. Januar 2014 12:16
An: Wel, Mars <wel.s@dolo.de>
Betreff: RE: Prod Order

 

Dear Donnes;

Good day

 
A few minutes before ı placed the order.

 
If you need any assistance we are happy to help with that.

 

 

Best Regards

 

Korayae Vinay

Managing Director
"""
```

Any suggestions?

The code I tried is below:

```
re.findall('(?:(?:With best regards,|Best Regards,)\s*.*(?:Von:|From:))', body, flags = re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
Note: body is the body of the extracted email.
```

The Output I received:

```
With Regards,
dcabv,
vce technologies
vce.com
cont:+00440044


From: abc@gsn.com
To:csd@scb.com
Sub: product

Dear Sir,
Can I get the update of my order?

With Regards,
abc
cont:+46346466

Von:
```

But I want the output to be splitted into two as
1st output will be from 'With Regards' of 1st email til 'From'.

2nd output will be from 'With Regards' of 2nd email til 'Von'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all the lines below signature line don't contain an empty line, you may use:

```bash
(?mi)^with(?:\s+best)?\s+regards.*(?:\n.+)+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vPthrL/1)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `(?mi)`: Ignore Case and Multi line Mode
- `^`: Start
- `with`: Match test `with`
- `(?:\s+best)?`: Optionally match 1+ spaces followed by `best`
- `\s+regards`: match 1+ spaces followed by `regards`
- `.*`: Match everything else till end of line
- `(?:\n.+)+`: Match 1+ of any characters followed by line break. Repeat this group 1+ times

---

##### Update:

Based on your edited question, you may use this regex:

```bash
(?mi)^(?:with\s+)?(?:best\s+)?regards.*(?:\n(?!von:|from:).*)+
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/vPthrL/3)

Here `(?!von:|from:)` is a negative lookahead to stop the match when we encounter `von:` or `from:` on next line.

Comment: Thanks much for the help. It is very useful.

@anubhava, I tried with my text based on ur logic but I'm getting the both the body as well.  I have edited the question with the another text. Can you pls let me know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: For the updated text here is the demo: https://regex101.com/r/vPthrL/2 Can you tell me what's not working in this?

Comment: The output includes the body of the 2nd email as well instead of only signature.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Make sure to use `(?mi)` to enable `MULTILINE` mode also. You probably need to use regex below `Update` section of my answer.